# Java module not found at runtime even with requires transitive

Tags: java, eclipse, java-module

While migrating our project from Java 8 to Java 11 modules, I have a question concerning the Java Module System (JPMS), especially to the *required transitive* directive. Lets assume we have four simple projects A, B, C and D with the following module declarations in *module-info.java*:

**Project A**

```
open module a {
    exports a;
}
```

**Project B**

```
open module b {
    exports b;
    requires transitive a;
}
```

**Project C**

```
open module c {
    exports c;
    requires transitive b;
}
```

**Project D**

```
open module d {
    requires transitive c;
}
```

Using Maven, we declared the dependencies *D depends on C, C depends on B and B depends on A* in the corresponding *pom.xml* files. Besides, each project contains a class file with the following content (the files for projects A, B and C are equivalent):

```
package d;
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("D");
    }
}
```

When running the classes using the default runtime configuration of Eclipse 2018-12, only class A, B and C runs without errors. But when I run class D I get: ***Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module a not found, required by b***

In my understanding module *a* should be known to module *b*, module *c* and also module *d* due to applied *requires transitive* directives. But as you can see, at runtime this is not the case since module *a* is not set in the *module-path* *(-p)* but on the *classpath* of the generated command line:

```
C:\me\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javaw.exe
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-p "C:\me\workspace\d\target\classes;C:\me\workspace\c\target\classes;C:\me\workspace\b\target\classes"
-classpath "C:\me\workspace\a\target\classes"
-m d/d.D
```

**So my question is:** Why project A (*C:\me\workspace\a\target\classes*) has been added to the *classpath* and not to the *module-path*? Is this intended behaviour, and what do I have to change to get project D running in Eclipse?

If I move *C:\me\workspace\a\target\classes* to the *-p* argument list, everything works as I would expect but that's surely not the preferred way to go.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Does selection project _d_, in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Projects_ moving project _a_ from _Classpath_ to _Modulepath_ fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger: No, it didn't (btw., on this tab there were neither classpath nor modulepath entries shown, so I had not to move but to add a new entry for project _a_). But, if I add module _a_ it in my Run configuration > Dependencies > Modulepath entries it works. Meanwhile I also found that when I add _requires a_ in module _c_ or module _d_ it will also work. For now, it is a workaround that we can live with, but actually I want to understand why my _required transient_ directives are not enough to add all necessary modules to the _module-path_ when running class _D_.

Comment: I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543766

Comment: Well, then you can give yourself an answer. Vote and comment on the bug if you want it to be fixed.